# How does the CLR handle the Config-Settings

Tags: c#

I'm quite confused, how the Config-Files are handled: There is basically one Config per Application, which is loaded somewhere and can get accessed quite easily.
But we have DLLs which are invoked dynamically via reflection and even they can get Data from the Config. How is this possible?

Or even more: If the DLLs are in another Server/Location, how can get they the Data they need?

I know how to use the Config-Files with Transform etc., but I find no good Articles, where the informations are saved in the Memory and how the magic of spreading the Data is happening.

Comment: A app.exe.config file is a big deal, the CLR uses it to configure the primary AppDomain before it starts your EXE.  Necessary because there can't be an AppDomainSetup yet, a chicken-and-egg problem.  There is *no* .config file for DLLs, they are expected to play along with whatever EXE loads them.  If you need config to make a DLL perform correctly regardless of what EXE uses them then you'll need a separate XML file or expose configuration settings as properties so the EXE can set them.

Comment: So the Config-data is loaded in the AppDomain, but it can be shared among all places, is there some hidden magic we will next explore how this is working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with [Configuring Apps by using Configuration Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y(v=vs.110).aspx). Important concepts:

- The .NET runtime is configured globally per machine using the Machine.config file located in the [runtime path]\Config\ directory.
- Machine configuration can be overwritten per application.
- Application config files also contain application-specific settings.

Configuration details depend on how your application is hosted. ASP.NET apps and their relatives (MVC, Web API, etc) have a complex configuration hierarchy. After the Machine.config, there's an IIS ApplicationHost.config, a possible config file in the web root, config for your web site, and then optional configuration for each sub-directory in your application. You can read more about it in [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx).

Standalone apps like forms applications, console apps, and Windows services have a single configuration file with the naming convention [app name].exe.config.

Beyond that, the runtime makes all configuration available to loaded assemblies with the static [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class. There's no real magic. The ConfigurationManager is simply a singleton abstraction over the final merged configuration state (the most local setting wins).

If your configuration data is more complex than keys and values, consider [Creating a custom Configuration Section in .NET](http://joelabrahamsson.com/creating-a-custom-configuration-section-in-net/).

There's no out-of-the-box support for reading configuration files on external servers/locations. It is possible, however, by implementing a [ProtectedConfigurationProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfc2t3az(v=vs.100).aspx). Typically, this provider is used for non-default configuration encryption. With a little creativity, it can be hacked to allow us to store configuration data anywhere we like. For details, see [A Simple Trick to Centralize your .NET configuration](http://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/a-simple-trick-to-centralize-your-net-configurati-1).